# qmake's "project MESSAGE" messages suppression

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

Can I suppress qmake's "Project MESSAGE" messages? For example, "Project MESSAGE: This project is using private headers and will therefore be tied to this specific Qt module build version.". Or, can I at least setup Qt Creator to not to show this messages in "General Messages" output pane?

Comment: You shouldn't care about any of it, but since you evidently do, patch your copy of Qt Creator to ignore such messages, or patch your copy of Qt to remove the messages.

Comment: Reading that message I'm inclined to think the project I'm trying to build depends on specific Qt version. So I should switch to that Qt version and message will disapear and my project will build fine. Am I correct?